# How to retrieve all user-entered Google Fit activities in Android?

Tags: android, google-fit

I need to obtain activities such as yoga, ski, pilates etc, these acitvities:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessActivities

The documentation cannot be any more scarce:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/ConfigApi

in their example I need to know the name of the custom activity, but how do I know what activities has the user entered? Is this even the right api for this? (The `ConfigApi`) How do I obtain a list of the user-added activities?

EDIT: I think I might need the SessionsApi instead of the ConfigApi but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You may use the [Sessions API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SessionsApi) in creating and managing [sessions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Session) of user activity in Google Fit.

> The [`startSession(GoogleApiClient, Session)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SessionsApi.html#startSession(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Session)) and [`stopSession(GoogleApiClient, String)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SessionsApi.html#stopSession(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, java.lang.String)) methods mark the time range of the session. Data inserted using the [HistoryApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryApi.html) during the period where the session is in progress will be associated with that Session once it is stopped.
>
> Once a session has been saved, it can be retrieved using [`readSession(GoogleApiClient, SessionReadRequest)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SessionsApi.html#readSession(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.SessionReadRequest)).

Here's a sample [project](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-sessions-api--cms-25857).